# How to change the index value in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
arr = [10,22,5,36,9]
length =len(arr)
for i in range(length):
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]):
            arr[i]=arr[i]
        elif(arr[i] > arr[i+1]):
            p=arr[i+1]
            arr[i+1]=arr[i]
            arr[i]=p
print(arr)
```

I have got an error in line 5 as IndexError: list index out of range. Please help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you try to iterate with "i" but its max value is the length of the array, so i+1 is larger and it goes out of bounds.

With just that snippet it's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but you can try like this (changed the range to get to length-1):

```
arr = [10,22,5,36,9]
length = len(arr)
for i in range(length-1):
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]):
            arr[i]=arr[i]
        elif(arr[i] > arr[i+1]):
            p=arr[i+1]
            arr[i+1]=arr[i]
            arr[i]=p
print(arr)
```

Comment: Looks like he's trying to sort an array? Either way the `arr[i]=arr[i]` part seems useless to me.

Comment: I want to sort the array to find the largest number.